# Getting error while generating crypto keys using GCloud KMS to access private repo as dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to add encrypted ssh keys to google KMS using this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/access-private-github-repos) for accessing private repository as a dependency on Google App Engine (Node.JS project).

I have successfully generated Cloud KMS KeyRing and CryptoKey but I'm facing an error while encrypting the key.

> (gcloud.kms.encrypt) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission
>   'cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.useToEncrypt' denied for resource
>   'projects/test/locations/global/keyRings/my-keyring/cryptoKeys/key'.

Need some help to setup this so can I can use this ssh key on GAE.

Comment: Please do not show your problem using screenshots. This prevents others from searching on a similar issue and prevents them from finding your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley Apologies, I have added the line in which I'm facing the issue.

Comment: My answer explains what is wrong and how to correct it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have IAM permissions to use to encrypt feature.

Advice: do not practice on your SSH real keys. Make a copy of them into a different directory. Then learn how to use IAM and KMS on the copies.

> Need some help to setup this so can I can use this ssh key on GAE.

I not sure what you are trying accomplish with KMS encrypting SSH keys for use on GAE.

> To allow a user or service account to use a key to encrypt or decrypt
>   using a particular key, they must have the
>   cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter, cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypter,
>   cloudkms.cryptoKeyDecrypter, or owner role, as per the chart in
>   Permissions and Roles.

Example command to grant a service account permissions:

```
gcloud kms keys add-iam-policy-binding \
  golden-egg --location global --keyring golden-goose \
  --member serviceAccount:my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --role roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter
```

Similar command to grant a user permissions:

```
gcloud kms keys add-iam-policy-binding \
  golden-egg --location global --keyring golden-goose \
  --member user:sillygoose@gmail.com \
  --role roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter
```

[Granting permissions to use keys](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/iam#granting_permissions_to_use_keys)

[Permissions and Roles](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/permissions-and-roles)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the response. Actually I'm trying to allow access to private git repository which is a dependency in my package.json file. So for doing this, I need  to use Cloud KMS.
If this is a permission issue then I would ask my organisation to allow the access to Cloud KMS in service account.

Comment: Correct, you do not have permission to encrypt. You project owner will need to add the correct permissions to the service account.

Answer (score 1):

Enable settings on CloudBuild

Cloud Build -> settings > Cloud KMS - Cloud KMS CryptoKey Decrypter -> enabled

Its worked to me