# How to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS running on GCP Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I am using windows for running local appengine for my golang project.
I was getting `googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.useToEncrypt' denied on resource 'projects/xxxx/locations/xxxx/keyRings/xxx/cryptoKeys/xxx' (or it may not exist)., forbidden`. Then I resolved by setting environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with the value of service account xxxx.json.
Then deployed in `GCP` appengine it return same error `googleapi: Error 403.....`
So how to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in GCP appengine.

Answer (score 13):

The problem that you are having is caused by developing/testing in two environments: your desktop and App Engine. This problem is easy to solve in a clean and secure way.

When developing/testing on your desktop, use a service account. Use an environment variable to specify the service account.

On Windows:

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=c:\fullpath\serviceaccount.json
```

On Linux:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/fullpath/serviceaccount.json
```

You can run the previous command manually at the command prompt or put it into a startup script (Linux) or a system environment variable (Windows).

For App Engine, I do not recommend using a service account file in your application. I also do not recommend setting the environment variable.

Google Client libraries support Application Default Credentials (ADC). This means that the libraries will attempt to find credentials for you automatically. The Client libraries can then use the environment to find the service account to use on Windows and automatically use the App Engine Default Service Account when deployed.

[Google Cloud Application Default Credentials](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-application-default-credentials/)]

By including ADC in your code, you can test on Windows/Linux and deploy to App Engine without modifying your code and without the security risks of including a service account JSON file in your deployment.

Comment: @NiklasR. For Google App Engine Standard, the environment variable is not needed. The Google Clients obtain the credentials from the default service account assigned to App Engine. This link has more information: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/service-account

Comment: This is another example of modern engineering, where only 90% of the functionality or less actually works. ADC doesn't work for generating Google Cloud Storage signed URLs. For that, you need the full JSON. And App Engine doesn't allow you to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. I checked. In the AE Docker image, every env var I set is there except that one. I guess I have to find a way to connect my laptop to production so it can sign URLs.

Comment: @ThrowAwayAccount - There are two methods to sign data. The first is to use the RSA private key located in the JSON key material. When the private key is not available, then you use the IAM SignBlob API. The API is [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob). The functionality is in the Google Cloud SDK for every supported language. Also, supported via a simple HTTP REST request. Using the IAM method is secure as the service account JSON key material is not required and is preferred over using the RSA private key.

Comment: @ThrowAwayAccount - If you search on Stack Overflow you will see Signed URL examples that support both RSA and IAM signing methods. A very simple problem to solve if you understand the underlying services. Which method to select is determined by your security requirements. If you have a problem, create a question. We can help you with a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

As of now set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json does not seems to work
Here is how you can do it
run this command in

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

and it will set the application default key automatically

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up IAM permissions to use the encrypt feature.

You can do that by using the following command with your service account's details:

```
gcloud kms keys add-iam-policy-binding \
  golden-egg --location global --keyring golden-goose \
  --member serviceAccount:my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --role roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter
```

Here is a [community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150044/getting-error-while-generating-crypto-keys-using-gcloud-kms-to-access-private-re) that already touched the subject and can give you some more information and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer:

In your console, Under IAM -> Service Accounts you will be able to find the service account associated with your app engine instance:

[image]

You can edit the permissions there or via the command line.

Sometimes it's easier to do things via the UI

Comment: By default the App Engine default service account already has the Editor role in the project and read/write access to all resources within that project.

Comment: @Daniel Lee let me do by giving `Editor` role to the service account

Comment: @Daniel Lee, I was given `Editor` role to the service account under `xxx-xxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`, but again getting `googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.useToEncrypt' denied on resource 'projects/xxxxxxxx/locations/xxxxxx/keyRings/xxx/cryptoKeys/xxx' (or it may not exist)., forbidden`

Comment: @THIYAGARAJAN SR, Try adding this role: `cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter`, the role that has this specific function. The `Editor` role will not give you enough permission to do that.